# Left Outer Join Puxando Somente Dados Contidos

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer esta pesquisa para saber quantas criancas e gestantes cada visitador atende mas só esta puxando as familias que tem gestantes mesmo colocando o bendito `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, é por causa da clausula `ON`?

Nao consigo pensar em outra forma pois só as tabelas criancas e gestantes estao ligadas pela familia, tem alguma alternativa para puxar todas as familias tendo ou nao gestante?

```
SELECT          X_Crs.crs
            ,   M.nome
            ,   X_Visitador.visitador
            ,   X_Familia.familia
            ,   X_Gestante.nome
FROM            X_Familia
            ,   X_Visitador
LEFT JOIN       X_Municipio M   ON M.municipio          = X_Visitador.municipio
INNER JOIN      X_Crs           ON X_Crs.crs            = M.crs
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_Gestante      ON X_Gestante.familia   = X_Familia.familia
WHERE           X_Visitador.situacao    = '1' 
            AND X_Familia.situacao      = '1' 
            AND X_Gestante.situacao     = '1'  
            AND X_Gestante.statusErro   IS NULL 
            AND X_Familia.visitador     = X_Visitador.visitador
ORDER BY        crs
            ,   M.nome
            ,   visitador
            ,   familia;
```

Comment: Não, é por causa das condições adicionais sobre essa tabela no `WHERE`. Mova essas condições para o `ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo as indicações do utilizador [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto), além de algum *refactoring* e otimização:

```
SELECT      XC.crs
        ,   XM.nome
        ,   XV.visitador
        ,   XF.familia
        ,   IFNULL(XG.nome, '') AS NomeGestante
FROM        X_Familia   XF
INNER JOIN  X_Visitador XV  ON  XV.visitador    = XF.visitador
LEFT JOIN   X_Municipio XM  ON  XM.municipio    = XV.municipio
INNER JOIN  X_Crs       XC  ON  XC.crs          = XM.crs
LEFT JOIN   X_Gestante  XG  ON  XG.familia      = XF.familia
                            AND XG.situacao     = '1'
                            AND XG.statusErro   IS NULL 
WHERE       XV.situacao     = '1' 
        AND XF.situacao     = '1' 
ORDER BY    XC.crs
        ,   XM.nome
        ,   XV.visitador
        ,   XF.familia
```

Comment: So troquei o ISNULL por IFNULL que funciona no MyQSL mas deu certo, muito muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Resposta editada com o IFNULL! Dê um up na resposta e marque-a como aceite :)